# Automate Angular 8 app deployment to Elastic Beanstalk with codepipeline

Tags: angular, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to deploy an angular app Elastic Beanstalk with codepipeline. Everything going file ,only deploy gets failed with error message "Provide one of these files:Dockerrun.aws.json". Below is buildspec.yml file-

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
    commands:
      - echo Installing angular cli...
      - npm install
      - npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.29
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started...
      - npm run build-prod
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Post Build started...
      - cd output
      - zip -r -D output.zip *
      - cd ..
      - mv output/output.zip output.zip 
artifacts:
  files:
    - output.zip
```

But i have included custom-nginx-file.conf,Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json inside final zip folder. any idea why ebs cand find these files?

Comment: Where does `Dockerrun.aws.json` come from? What is the structure of `output.zip`?

Comment: actually i have configured ebs platform as Docker.that why it needs Dockerrun.aws.json..below is the structure of output.zip--`output 
  dist
  custom-nginx-file.conf
  Dockerfile 
  Dockerrun.aws.json`     and when i manually upload the zip file its working fine

Comment: Can you got to CB bucket, and inspect the resulting artifacts that get submitted to EB? The artifact file will probably have some strange name without extension, but it is just a zip.